# Is it possible to merge forward declaration and regular declaration into a single file, then use it as if they're separated?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I have this crazy idea of merging forward declaration headers and actual declaration files into one by performing some macro trickery. To provide some context, the daily policy I follow for forward declarations is as follows;

- Each header file has its "_fwd.hpp" complement, which contains forward declarations of all forward-declarable entities in that header file.
- I include the forward declaration header where forward-declaration of the actual thing suffices
- I include the regular declaration header mainly in .cpp files and only when an actual implementation information is required (things requiring size of the implementation, inheritance etc.)

But having a separate _fwd.hpp header for each header pollutes the project, and is kind of hard to maintain. So, I come up with the following idea of merging forward declaration and actual declaration into single file, then enabling them according to include count. I come up with this initial idea of double-inclusion of header;

foo.hpp

```
#if !defined(FOO_FWD_H)
#define FOO_FWD_H
    // Forward declarations goes here
    struct foo;
#else // has forward_declaration, include actual if not included yet

#if !defined(FOO_H)
    #define FOO_H
    struct foo{
       foo(){/*....*/}
    };
    // Normal declarations goes here
#endif // FOO_H

#endif // FOO_FWD_H
```

If I include "foo.hpp" once, I get forward declaration of foo, but if I include it second time in a translation unit, I get the forward & actual declaration of the foo, which is totally fine by me. (as I'm kinda doing the same thing anyway, include fwdecl in header, actual in cpp).

So, when put into use case described above, it goes like this;

**bar.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "foo.hpp" // forward declaration

struct bar{
    bar(const foo& f);
};
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include "bar.hpp" // bar + 1st inclusion of foo.hpp
#include "foo.hpp" // included 2nd time, actual implementation enabled

bar::bar(const foo& f){
    f.rab(); // requires actual implementation
}
```

But as you can imagine, this approach has problems. The biggest issue is, if foo.hpp included by another header, tar.hpp, and tar.hpp is included in bar.hpp, causes actual implementation to be exposed to bar.hpp, defeating the purpose. Also, when actual implementation of foo.hpp is required in bar.hpp, it has to be included twice, which looks weird (linters and tools like iwyu might have an issue with that).

So the question boils down to this, can we actually make this work in such a way that;

- including headers which using this idiom does not interfere with other headers' inclusion state
- eliminating the need of double-inclusion when actual implementation is needed

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** (30/10/19 10:57 PM GMT+2)

Improved version of idiom based on @IanAbbott 's answer:

Try it live : [repl.it](https://repl.it/@mustafakemalgil/single-fwdecl-decl)

**foo.hpp** (our single fwdecl & decl idiom implementing header)

```cpp
    // (mgilor): we got ourselves quite a lot boilerplate code, 
    // maybe x-macro concept help us to move away boilerplate to
    // a separate file?

    #if defined(FOO_FWD_ONLY)
        #undef FOO_FWD_HPP // prevent accidental implementation inclusion on other headers
    #endif

    #if defined(FOO_FWD_ONLY) && !defined(FOO_FWD_HPP) 
        #define FOO_FWD_HPP 
        // forward declarations go here
        struct foo;
    #elif !defined(FOO_FWD_ONLY)

         // includer wants the full monty
        #if !defined(FOO_HPP)
            #define FOO_HPP
            // actual declarations go here

            struct foo{
                foo(){/*....*/}
                void do_things(){}
            };

        #endif // FOO_HPP

    #endif // FOO_FWD_HPP

    // undef the macro, so future includes does not get affected
    #undef FOO_FWD_ONLY
```

**tar.hpp** (fwdecl only consumer of foo)

```cpp
    #pragma once

    #define FOO_FWD_ONLY
    #include "foo.hpp" // this header needs forward declaration

    #ifdef FOO_FWD_HPP 
        #pragma message ( __FILE__ " has forward declaration of foo") 
    #endif
    #ifdef FOO_HPP
        #pragma message ( __FILE__ " has full declaration of foo") 
    #endif

    struct tar{
        tar(foo & f){ }
    };
```

**bar.hpp** (fwdecl only consumer of foo, also consumes tar.hpp)

```cpp
    #pragma once

    #include "tar.hpp" // tar consumed foo fwdecl-only
    #define FOO_FWD_ONLY
    #include "foo.hpp" // bar needs fwdecl-only

    #ifdef FOO_FWD_HPP 
        #pragma message ( __FILE__ " has forward declaration of foo") 
    #endif
    #ifdef FOO_HPP
        #pragma message ( __FILE__ " has full declaration of foo") 
    #endif

    struct bar{
        bar(foo & f);
    };
```

**bar.cpp** (full decl consumer of bar & foo)

```cpp
    #include "bar.hpp"
    #include "foo.hpp" // second inclusion, should enable full definition

    #ifdef FOO_FWD_HPP 
        #pragma message ( __FILE__ " has forward declaration of foo") 
    #endif
    #ifdef FOO_HPP
        #pragma message ( __FILE__ " has full declaration of foo") 
    #endif

    bar::bar(foo& ref){
        ref.do_things();
    }
```

**baz.hpp** (no dependencies)

```cpp
    #pragma once

    struct baz{
        void do_baz();
    };
```

**baz.cpp** (full decl consumer of foo & baz)

```cpp
    #include "baz.hpp"
    #include "foo.hpp"  // no prior include of foo, but since FOO_FWD_ONLY is not defined
                        // baz.cpp will get full declaration.

    #ifdef FOO_FWD_HPP 
        #pragma message ( __FILE__ " has forward declaration of foo") 
    #endif
    #ifdef FOO_HPP
        #pragma message ( __FILE__ " has full declaration of foo") 
    #endif


    void baz::do_baz(){
        foo f;
        f.do_things(); // completely fine.
    }
```

**main.cpp** (consuming application)

```cpp
    // consuming application
    #include "tar.hpp" 
    #include "bar.hpp" 
    #include "foo.hpp"  // already has previous foo fwdecl, so second inclusion will enable full declaration. 
                        // (also FOO_FWD_ONLY is not defined, so first inclusion would enable it too)
    #include "baz.hpp"
    int main(void){

        foo f;
        tar t(f);
        bar b(f);
        baz bz;
    }
```

Output when compiled:

```
    tar.hpp:7:13: warning: tar.hpp has forward declaration of foo 
    bar.hpp:8:13: warning: bar.hpp has forward declaration of foo 
    bar.cpp:6:13: warning: bar.cpp has forward declaration of foo 
    bar.cpp:9:13: warning: bar.cpp has full declaration of foo 
    baz.cpp:9:13: warning: baz.cpp has full declaration of foo 
    tar.hpp:7:13: warning: tar.hpp has forward declaration of foo 
    bar.hpp:8:13: warning: bar.hpp has forward declaration of foo
```

Comment: Read up on the "undef-free X-macro" concept. That can do the trick.

Comment: please pick one language. They will probably have different solutions. As your code is C++, I guess you want that

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I prefer C++, but AFAIK both c & c++  follows the same preprocessor rules, so answer should be applicable to both (assuming the solution does not depend on language-specific constructs like __has_include etc.)

Comment: c++ can avoid the need for most macros, in c I dont know, but if you insist on using them, then actually double tagging is fine

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for the comment, i'll check it

Comment: Why do you need the `_fwd.hpp` files? What problem do they solve? A real minimal example would be nice to understand what we're dealing with.

Comment: How is this better then just writing two files? One with forward declaration and the other with the definition? Then you include the definition only if you need it. All other files include only the declaration file. In your example you include definition if you include the same file twice.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I use them mainly for two purposes, to minimize the amount of indirect include definitions in consuming code, and to reduce compile times. Usual forward declaration benefits.

Comment: @KamilCuk The focal point of this question is, that "I don't want to write two separate files", and the approach I presented is towards to achieve that. This is more like a style thing.

Comment: You could just add the forward declarations explicitly where required, rather than including a header. I.e. in "bar.hpp", replace `#include "foo.hpp"` with `struct foo;`.

Comment: @MustafaKemalGILOR I can see how that can help those situations, but it's quite a bit of work to maintain - and there are caching solutions that can help with keeping the compilation times down.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah it is. I'm already using ccache, and I'm aware of upcoming "c++ modules" will solve the need of forward declaration and header guards. I just wonder if it's possible at all to achieve the thing I proposed, because I have never seen a project utilizing stuff like this until now. Pure curiosity.

Comment: @MustafaKemalGILOR Then i think it's better to do like the `_KERNEL` does. And `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` and `_GNU_SOURCE` and all the happy [feature_test_macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html). Och, and `FUSE_USE_VERSION` serves similar purpose. The header that needs the implementation declares a macro like `FOO_NEED_DECLARATION` before including anything.

Comment: @IanAbbott yeah, I could do that, but it is harder to maintain, and harder to perform name/namespace changes. also I want to be able to provide forward declarations to consumers, so they don't have to look up into header files to write their own forward declarations (looking from a library/framework writer's perspective). It becomes cumbersome especially when template classes are being forward-declared. (and they might have default template parameters and such.). As I library consumer, I wouldn't want to delve into library internals if I just want to forward-declare a library thing.

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah, I thought about `FOO_NEED_DECLARATION` too, but in most cases you would need to undef it after use, to not interfere with other headers. I thought wrapping #include in a macro but that way is blocked too, as preprocessor processes each unit for only once. A custom `_Include` built-in would solve the issue (like in #pragma case), but I am not aware of any compiler which implements such a facility.

Comment: Rather than `FOO_NEED_DECLARATION`, you could have `FOO_FWD_ONLY`, so the header that only needs forward declarations from "foo.h" could define that macro before `#include "foo.h" and undefine it afterwards. Or you could undefine it inside "foo.h" itself for ease of maintenance.

Comment: What do you mean by "actual declaration"?  Do you mean "definition"?

Comment: @WilliamPursell what I mean with actual declaration is the non-forward declaration of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal for consideration (maybe not the best). It involves the includer of an include file setting a macro to indicate that it only needs the forward declarations from that include file. When the macro is not defined, it gets everything from the include file. To avoid problems with header files forgetting to undefine the special macro afterwards, the file being included can be made responsible for undefining it.

It goes something like this:

**foo.hpp**

```
#if !defined(FOO_FWD_HPP)
#define FOO_FWD_HPP

// forward declarations go here

struct foo;

#endif // FOO_FWD_HPP

#if !defined(FOO_FWD_ONLY)
// includer wants the full monty
#if !defined(FOO_HPP)
#define FOO_HPP

// normal declarations go here

struct foo{
   foo(){/*....*/}
};

#endif // FOO_HPP
#endif // FOO_FWD_ONLY

#undef FOO_FWD_ONLY
```

**bar.hpp**

```
#pragma once

// only need forward declarations from foo.hpp
#define FOO_FWD_ONLY
#include "foo.hpp"

struct bar {
    bar(const foo& f);
};
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include "bar.hpp"
#include "foo.hpp"

bar::bar(const foo& f){
    f.rab(); // requires actual implementation
}
```

The main benefit is to reduce the amount of code being compiled. It does not do anything to fix the problem of unintended exposure. For example, if "bar.hpp" includes some other file that includes "foo.hpp" without defining the `FOO_FWD_ONLY` macro first, the full definitions from "foo.hpp" will be exposed to the remainder of "bar.hpp".

Comment: Your implementation gave me an idea to work around double inclusion issue. Working on it right now.